# MongoDB projection - include some first level keys and matched subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

***update at the top because it's important:***

> The following problem existed, but it's based on a duplicate key. I
> used Robo 3T to edit my data (no notice/error about the duplicate).
>
> My posted code works, if there is no duplicate key in the document.

***initial post:***

Trying to get the matching sub document and some first level keys.

Dot notation works, but I can't get both (first level & sub document) at the same time.
Using MongoDB 4.4 and Mongoose.

```json
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "wanted" : "something",
    "ignore": "bar",
    "sub" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "name" : "foo"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "foo",
}
```

My query:

```js
collection.findOne(
    {
        _id: 1,
        'sub._id': 5,
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        wanted: 1,
        'sub.$': 1,
    }
);
```

That's what I want:

```json
{
    "wanted" : "something",
    "sub" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "name" : "foo"
        }
    ],
}
```

But I can get only the matching sub document or the top level key (`wanted`). Not both with a single query. I don't want to return the full document.

I am relative new to MongoDB, but I thought I already had a solution for this weeks ago, but can't find it anymore or it was a dream =)

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `'sub._id': 5`

Comment: This will also return the sub document `_id`, but not `name`. It just overwrites the sub document. You could also change the value of _id if you want of add new values.

Comment: I mean change `'users._id': 5` to `'sub._id': 5`

Comment: Sure, typo. Doesn't exists in my code. Sorry and great you saw it! But the problem was based on duplicate key in my db. I have updated my question. But it's solved because my code works if there is no duplicate key.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub._id` instead of `users._id` to solve the problem, additionally you can use `$filter` with `find()`

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: 1
},
{
  _id: 0,
  wanted: 1,
  "sub": {
    $filter: {
      input: "$sub",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this._id",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6xmOd67X7c-)**

Or you can use `elemMatch`

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: 1,
  sub: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      _id: 5
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  wanted: 1,
  "sub.$": 1,
  
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h23oUKWF8Nx)**

Comment: Thanks @varman, I played around with your playgrounds. But it didn't worked with my data. So i moved my data to the playground. Result was an error: Duplicate key. Damn it... But thank you so much! Wouldn't have seen it that fast.

Comment: @klabak does the answer help you?